# Angular CircleCI /usr/bin/xvfb-run: 183: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: ng: not found

Tags: angular, circleci

I'm trying to integrate CricleCi with Angular but with no luck..

That's the case:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
xvfb-run -a ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage --watch=false
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 183: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: ng: not found
Exited with code 127
```

config.yml

```
   version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        working_directory: ~/my-project
        docker:
        - image: circleci/node:8-browsers
        steps:
        - checkout
        - restore_cache:
            key: AngularCircleCI-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        - run: npm install
        - save_cache:
            key: AngularCircleCI-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            paths:
            - "node_modules"
        - run: xvfb-run -a ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage --watch=false
        - run: xvfb-run -a npm run e2e -- --no-progress --config=protractor-ci.conf.js
```

Any suggestion would be helpful...

Configuration:

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.2
Node: 10.10.0
OS: linux x64
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.2
```

Comment: You don't have the CLI installed *globally*

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem :( I've edited my post that you can check my config

Comment: You don't seem to have changed anything in the circle config, though.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Have you tried adding a step to install the CLI globally in the container, actually adding the ng command to the path? I.e. doing the same things you did to get it running locally.

Comment: changing run npm install to     - run: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli done job! Thank you!